# My animation wont move in PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My main code in the loop works fine by itself but for some reason this wont move and stays on the first image. Please help. Im new to this. The main loop executes fine by itself in another program but when i add the thing at the start to create the base it doesnt work. My only theory is that the base thing has to be in the main loop?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

Window = pygame.display.set_mode((480,48))
pygame.display.set_caption("Mario Animation")

black = (0,0,0)

#Takes in the image for the base
Base1 = pygame.image.load("images/Base1.png")
Base2 = pygame.image.load("images/Base2.png")
Base3 = pygame.image.load("images/Base3.png")

#Takes the sprites for mario
MarioRunning1 = pygame.image.load("images/Mario1.png")
MarioRunning2 = pygame.image.load("images/Mario1.png")
MarioRunning3 = pygame.image.load("images/Mario1.png")

BaseX = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

for i in range (10):
     Window.blit(Base1, ((BaseX,32)))
     BaseX=BaseX+16
     Window.blit(Base2, ((BaseX,32)))
     BaseX=BaseX+16
     Window.blit(Base3, ((BaseX,32)))
     BaseX=BaseX+16

CurrentImage = 1

MainLoop = True
while MainLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):
            MainLoop = False

    if (CurrentImage == 1): 
        Window.blit(MarioRunning3, (0,0))

    if (CurrentImage == 2):
        Window.blit(MarioRunning2, (0,0))

    if (CurrentImage == 3):
        Window.blit(MarioRunning1, (0,0))

    if (CurrentImage == 3):
        CurrentImage = 1

    else:
        CurrentImage+=1

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(5)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: MarioRunning[1-3] variables all represent the same image

Answer (score 0):

As @ChristianRapp said, the *MarioRunning* variables all refer to the said image, *Mario1.png*. Try changing that chunk to:

```
MarioRunning1 = pygame.image.load("images/Mario1.png")
MarioRunning2 = pygame.image.load("images/Mario2.png")
MarioRunning3 = pygame.image.load("images/Mario3.png")
```

That's assuming you have the 3 Mario sprites necessary. It also seems that you're never changing *CurrentImage* when you swap to an image, so it will always be *1*, and will never change. Try:

```
    if (CurrentImage == 1): 
        Window.blit(MarioRunning2, (0,0))
        CurrentImage = 2

    elif (CurrentImage == 2):
        Window.blit(MarioRunning3, (0,0))
        CurrentImage == 3

    else:
        Window.blit(MarioRunning1, (0,0))
        CurrentImage = 1
```

This way, it always goes to the next one in the cycle. Oh, and the reason the image won't move, is you're not telling it to. For example, the `(0, 0)` part of the line `Window.blit(MarioRunning1, (0,0))` tells pygame where to put the image, in pixels. Changing these numbers will change where the image is put.